# PHP - Connect mailbox office 365 with OAuth

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

Please forgive my amateurism both in php and on stackoverflow.
I have a PHP script that reads emails from an office 365 mailbox, for this I use a standard connection:

`$Inbox = imap_open('{Outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}', 'mabal@mydomain.com', 'mypassword');`

Then to read the new emails received, I used the command:

`$UnRead = imap_search($Inbox, 'UNSEEN');`

**Starting 20221001 - October 1, 2022, Microsoft will remove this authentication and require OAuth2 authentication.**

I registered my web application at **Microsoft Azure** and tried several settings. I have done a lot of research that allows me to connect to the mailbox to be able to read the mails without going through an interaction with a user. I've found nothing.

Does anyone have a step-by-step solution to retrieve a variable bound to an "imap_open" or do you have to use a completely different system.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you can use Microsoft Graph Api to get token and get mail box.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Did you got any reference? I'm also looking for similar problem. Please do let me know as  well.

Comment: [There was a plan dating back to 2020](https://wiki.php.net/todo/ext/imap/xoauth2) to update imap_open() to support XOAuth2, but it was never implemented. So you would need to switch to an alternative IMAP library that supports this, like [Horde IMAP Client](https://github.com/horde/Imap_Client) or [Zend/Laminas Mail](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-mail).

Comment: see this comment, a replacement was build  https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902

Answer (score 24):

It's been a wild ride for me and my coworkers but we found a solution.

## 1 - Configure your mail box in Azure

(I didn't do this part so i can't help you more than that ! )

**Edit :** Thanks to [parampal-pooni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292106/parampal-pooni), [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) explains how to configurate in azure.

You will need :

- The client Id
- The tenant Id
- The secret client
- The redirect Uri (Set it to http://localhost/test_imap)

## 2 - Grab a code to get a token

Construct this url :

```
$TENANT="5-48...";
$CLIENT_ID="c-9c-....";
$SCOPE="https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All";
$REDIRECT_URI="http://localhost/test_imap";

$authUri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $TENANT
           . '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=' . $CLIENT_ID
           . '&scope=' . $SCOPE
           . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($REDIRECT_URI)
           . '&response_type=code'
           . '&approval_prompt=auto';

echo($authUri);
```

Go to the link, connect to the mail box with the passeword.
Once it done, you will be redirect to : http://localhost/test_imap?code=LmpxSnTw...&session_state=b5d713....

Save the code (remove the '&' at the end !) and the session state inside the url.
**These codes expired after a few hours !**

## 3 - Get an access token

```
$CLIENT_ID="c-9c-....";
$CLIENT_SECRET="Y~tN...";
$TENANT="5-48...";
$SCOPE="https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access";
$CODE="LmpxSnTw...";
$SESSION="b5d713...";
$REDIRECT_URI="http://localhost/test_imap";

echo "Trying to authenticate the session..";

$url= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$param_post_curl = [ 
 'client_id'=>$CLIENT_ID,
 'scope'=>$SCOPE,
 'code'=>$CODE,
 'session_state'=>$SESSION,
 'client_secret'=>$CLIENT_SECRET,
 'redirect_uri'=>$REDIRECT_URI,
 'grant_type'=>'authorization_code' ];

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param_post_curl));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$oResult=curl_exec($ch);

echo "result : \n";

var_dump($oResult);
```

The access_token given in response is going to work **only for a few hours**. ( If your script is going to be launch on a daily basic you need to recreate a token. I'm going to show you how in the part 5 ! Save the refresh_token inside $oResult. If you don't have the "refresh_token" you have forgot to put "offline_access" in the scope)

**Edit :** I forgot to add the redirect_uri in this step, thank [jose ayram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1598884/jose-ayram)

## 4 - Connect to the mail box

Now choose your favorite library ;) ! We will use webklex/php-imap for this example (https://github.com/Webklex/php-imap)

```
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 
    
use Webklex\PHPIMAP\ClientManager;

$access_token="EH.j8s5z8...";
    
//$cm = new ClientManager($options = ["options" => ["debug" => true]]);                     
$cm = new ClientManager();                      
$client = $cm->make([
    'host'          => 'outlook.office365.com',                
    'port'          => 993,
    'encryption'    => 'ssl',
    'validate_cert' => false,
    'username'      => 'mymailbox@domain.com',
    'password'      => $access_token,
    'protocol'      => 'imap',
    'authentication' => "oauth"
]);

try {
    //Connect to the IMAP Server
    $client->connect();
    $folder = $client->getFolder('INBOX');
    $all_messages = $folder->query()->all()->get();
    //DONE ! :D     
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

## 5 - Connecting to the mail box everyday

```
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; 
    
use Webklex\PHPIMAP\ClientManager;

$CLIENT_ID="c-9c-....";
$CLIENT_SECRET="Y~tN...";
$TENANT="5-48...";
$REFRESH_TOKEN="EebH9H8S7...";

$url= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$param_post_curl = [ 
 'client_id'=>$CLIENT_ID,
 'client_secret'=>$CLIENT_SECRET,
 'refresh_token'=>$REFRESH_TOKEN,
 'grant_type'=>'refresh_token' ];

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param_post_curl));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//ONLY USE CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER AT FALSE IF YOU ARE IN LOCALHOST !!!
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// NOT IN LOCALHOST ? ERASE IT !

$oResult=curl_exec($ch);

echo("Trying to get the token.... \n");

if(!empty($oResult)){
    
    echo("Connecting to the mail box... \n");
    
    //The token is a JSON object
    $array_php_resul = json_decode($oResult,true);
    
    if( isset($array_php_resul["access_token"]) ){

        $access_token = $array_php_resul["access_token"];

        //$cm = new ClientManager($options = ["options" => ["debug" => true]]);                     
        $cm = new ClientManager();                      
        $client = $cm->make([
            'host'          => 'outlook.office365.com',                
            'port'          => 993,
            'encryption'    => 'ssl',
            'validate_cert' => false,
            'username'      => 'mymailbox@domain.com',
            'password'      => $access_token,
            'protocol'      => 'imap',
            'authentication' => "oauth"
        ]);
        
        try {
            //Connect to the IMAP Server
            $client->connect();
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }

    }else{
        echo('Error : '.$array_php_resul["error_description"]); 
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Just you must add the redirect_uri in the step3

Comment: You are right ! I just edited my answer. Thank you very much :) 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: This is it. THIS IS THE MILLION DOLLAR SOLUTION. 

Microsoft doesn't support client_credential + IMAP authorization but they haven't updated their documentation to reflect this feature IS STILL NOT AVAILABLE.

Thank you so much for providing this.

Comment: Shouldn't you be updating your saved refresh token every time you run it in step 5?

Comment: The refresh token allows you to generate a new acess token every time you  run the script. It never changes nor expire (maybe it will someday, but for me it's been 2 months and it's still good and running well :) ! Redo the step 3 if needed.)
I hope, i am clear in my explanation.

Comment: Is it still working? I am doing it by command without the OAuth and today at midnight it stopped working.

Comment: If you are talking about my script, it is still working fine. If you are talking about imap_open, it is not working for me since october.

Comment: To help with step 1 go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

Comment: im able to connect for a couple of runs of my script but on the third go it starts saying `stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://outlook.office365.com:993 (Operation timed out) in php-imap/src/Connection/Protocols/Protocol.php:204`

Comment: Di you try to remove the SSL verifypeer ? 
 // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)

Comment: Also if anyone was using the php's standard `imap` library before, id suggest switching to `php-imap2`: https://github.com/javanile/php-imap2 . Just * composer install; * replace all your functions from `imap_XXX` to `imap2_XXX`; * change your password inside `imap2_open` to be the `access_token`.

Comment: I have problem
I dont understand in 3 - Get an access token, what we are insert in this 2 fields

$CODE="LmpxSnTw...";
$SESSION="b5d713...";
and in 5 - Connecting to the mail box everyday I dont understand what I insert inside

$REFRESH_TOKEN="EebH9H8S7...";
If someone help me I will be grateful @Fox_In_Disguise

Comment: Hi @bidevgh, once you have finish the step 2 (going to the url you created and log to your mailbox), you will be redirected with a request Get. WHen you are on this new page look inside the url, you should have
htp:/localhost/test_imap?code=MyCodeIShouldSave&session_state=MySessionIShouldSave
This is the $CODE and the $SESSION you are looking for for the step 3

Comment: @bigdevgh, for the $REFRESH_TOKEN in step 5, you got it in the $oResult. When you finish the step 3. If you don't have the "refresh_token" you have forgot to put "offline_access" in the scope. Everything i'm telling you is currently written in my answer. Read carrefully my instructions after all the scripts ;) Good luck !

Comment: Do I have to manually do Step 2 everytime? Or I'll get the Refresh Token once that will be valid forever? This is the only thing missing for me! Thank you

Comment: @Fox_In_Disguise Is normal that I get this : Exception : Command failed to process: Causes: - Empty response Error occurred ?

Comment: @YannChabot, dot it just once :) The refresh token is valid for a very long time. I can't remember, but i think that it's 2 or 3 years. I might have read this in the microsoft documentation.

Comment: @user18966513 on which step did you get that ? This is in a curl response ?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I was tried a lot of things, but nothing worked... With your answer this is working!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, we performed all steps mentioned in this post BUT is stuck in an error below:
<< TAG1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed. >> TAG2 LIST "" "*" << TAG2 BAD User is authenticated but not connected. NULL >> TAG3 LOGOUT << * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server IMAP4 server signing off. << TAG3 OK LOGOUT completed.

Comment: @A-Ali On which step did you get this error ?

Comment: @Fox_In_Disguise, i am getting this error while calling  $client->connect();

Comment: Hi again, Related to my Issue, I tried testing the IMAP config at [link](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365) , The result was Ok **Connectivity Test Successful**, It seems that there is nothing wrong with the Imap settings , but there is some thing wrong while trying to fetch LIST "" * in our custom PHP app. Hope  some one can help me to resolve it . Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to use the debug to have more details on the errors ?

$cm = new ClientManager($options = ["options" => ["debug" => true]]); 

And are you sure, your refresh token is still good ? Have you tried to redo the steps 2 and 3 ?

Comment: @Fox_In_Disguise thanks for response.
Yes, we are using debug mode debug=true. If we don't use debug mode then no error is displayed.
Yes refresh token is good and we have also tried to regenerate the token by following the step 2 and step 3.

We get the json like this from getAccessToken function and we use refresh_token to get access_token for each connection :
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office365.com/User.Read",
"expires_in": 4397,
"ext_expires_in": 4397,
"access_token": "xxx",
"refresh_token": "xxx"
}

Comment: @A-Ali It's strange. It's seems that you do everything fine. I have reread your first comment and it looks like you are connecting the wrong user "BAD User is authenticated but not connected". In the end of the step 2, did you connect with the email account and the password of the mailbox you are trying to reach ?
I'm sorry that i can't give you the right answer. I'm only guessing, i never got this problem. Good luck.

Comment: @Fox_In_Disguise, thanks for your comments , after step 2 , we received a URL and successfully connect to the mailbox using the password.

Comment: Not sure if i did this wrong however mine expired after 3 months it seems. Not sure if I can change the expiry on refresh token or get a new one also so I can leave this be?

Comment: Service Principle added via power shell and given access to mailbox. @Fox_In_Disguise, do you get any idea how can we verify that service principle is successfully added and is there isnt any issue in that

Comment: Step #3 no longer works for me. I have formatted the curl request EXACTLY as shown, but I am getting the response "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'." It is definitely there, so why does it say that it's missing???

Answer (score 2):

1. Execute this curl
   Replace client_id, client_secret and tenant_id

> In scope you can try to use https://outlook.office365.com/.default, https://graph.microsoft.com/.default or https://outlook.office.com/.default

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id={CLIENT_ID}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office365.com%2F.default&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

2. PHP-imap login

```php
<?php 
// ....
$instance = new ClientManager();
$this->client = $instance->make([
    'host' => "outlook.office365.com",
    'port' => "993",
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'validate_cert' => true,
    'username' => "email@outlook.com",
    'password' => $curlAcessToken, // Access token curl
    'protocol' => 'imap',
    'authentication' => "oauth",
]);
```