# PHP - Connect office365 mailbox(OAuth) with refresh token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I'm new to this Azure/Office365 workflow. I'm working with office365 mailbox but I have a problem with refresh token process. I can get access token and refresh token with clientID and clientSecret process but when I try to use refresh token to obtain access token it always return as error.

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370661/php-connect-mailbox-office-365-with-oauth) as guideline for my code.

```
$CLIENT_ID="....";
$CLIENT_SECRET="...";
$TENANT="...";
$REFRESH_TOKEN="...";

$url= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$param_post_curl = [ 
 'client_id'=>$CLIENT_ID,
 'client_secret'=>$CLIENT_SECRET,
 'refresh_token'=>$REFRESH_TOKEN,
 'grant_type'=>'refresh_token' ];

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param_post_curl));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$oResult=curl_exec($ch);
```

My code look something like this and it always return

```
"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '7xxx...'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to look carefully on your curl options.
Mine is as following:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.$TENANT.'/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $param_post_curl,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Cookie: ; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd'

),
));


http_build_query is not good here I guess.
```